# Oracle query with two paterns in one expression

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Input:

```
TABLE NAME: SEARCH_RECORD

Column A   Column B  Column C  Column D
ID          CODE      WORD      CODE/WORD
--------------------------------------------
123          666Ani       RAT       666Ani/RAT
124          777Cae       CAT       777Cae/CAT
```

I need a query to check as a LIKE case

if i search with column B like '%6A' or column C '%A%' it will give result

suppose i want to get the like based on the column D search

```
**User will search like '%6A%'/'%AT%' (always / will be given by user)**
```

### **Expected output:**

```
    666Ani/RAT
```

so, I need a query for the above to get the ID as output (CASE query is preferable)

Need you valuable suggestion

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>It can't be done with simple like.</strike>
It should work if the pattern look like `'%6A%/%AT%'`. It is a valid pattern.

So, you can write: `columnD like '%6A%/%AT%'` or `columnD like first_pattern||'/'||second_pattern` if the come from as different variables.

Another approach, if you know for sure that there is only a `/`(you can check how many they are), may be to use two `like`s using `substr` to get first and then second part of the search string.

```
where
  columnB like substr(match_string, 1, instr(match_string,'/'))
  and 
  columnC like substr(match_string, instr(match_string,'/')+1)
```